# What is the voltage gain of an amplifier that produces an output of 750 mV for a 30uV input?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the voltage gain of an amplifier that produces an output of 750 mV for a 30uV input?

my solution:

Av-?
V out =750mv
V in = 30 mV

AV=? = V out/ V in = 750 mV / 30 mV =25

the answer is supposed to be 25,000 according to my teacher what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{Gain} = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{750\mathrm{mV}}{30\mu\mathrm{V}} \cdot \frac{1000 \mu\mathrm{V}}{1\mathrm{mV}} = 25 \cdot 1000 = 25000$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the input is specified in microvolts, not millivolts. You have to convert one or the other so you are comparing the same units. That's where the extra factor of $1000$ is coming from.

Comment: Thanks just realized that after posting lol :) but thank your for answering my question.